# Ansible with_dicts group_vars playbook

Tags: linux, ansible, ansible-playbook

My requirement is to get the below output in a file

```
 - targets: [ 'host1:port1', 'host2:port1' , 'host3:port1' ]                 
   job : hostgroup1     

 - targets: [ 'host1:port2', 'host2:port2' , 'host3:port3' ]                 
   job : hostgroup2
```

I have the input file as below and it should fetch the data from variables or group variables . Under Hostgroup1 I may have n number of hosts and under Hostgroup2 I may have n number of hosts

```
 Hostgroup1 : host1,host2,host3....n                                                    
 Hostgroup2 : host1,host2,host3....n
```

I am confused how to create jinja template and tasks to get this output

Comment: the input file isn't a standard format. if it were json or yaml it'd be much easier to parse

Comment: Please let me know how to create json or yml or jinja to get this output

Comment: Are the hostgroup1 and hostgroup2 groups in the ansible inventory?  Where is the port defined at?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I defined something like your data in the 'vars' section of a playbook.  You could put it in a vars file, or you could possibly define these vars in your hostvars/groupvars or something.  This probably isn't exactly what you want, but you can adapt it to your needs.

```
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  vars:
    data:
    - { "name": "hostgroup1", "port": 80, "hosts": ["host1", "host2", "host3"] }
    - { "name": "hostgroup2", "port": 443, "hosts": ["host5", "host6", "host7"] }
  tasks:
  - debug:
      msg: |
        {% for item in data %}
        - job: {{ item.name }}
          targets: [ {%- for host in item.hosts -%}
          "{{ host }}:{{ item.port }}",
          {%- endfor -%}]
        {% endfor %}
```

Output

```
# ANSIBLE_STDOUT_CALLBACK=debug ansible-playbook 20190404_sf_961529.yml 

PLAY [localhost] ************************************************************************************

TASK [debug] ****************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {}

MSG:

- job: hostgroup1
  targets: ["host1:80","host2:80","host3:80",]
- job: hostgroup2
  targets: ["host5:443","host6:443","host7:443",]


PLAY RECAP ******************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

For the output to a file you can use a task like this.

```
  - copy:
      dest: outputpath
      content: |
        {% for item in data %}
        - job: {{ item.name }}
          targets: [ {%- for host in item.hosts -%}
          "{{ host }}:{{ item.port }}",
          {%- endfor -%}]
        {% endfor %}
```

Comment: Hi Zoredache ..... Seriously this has helped me alot ..... I will get back to you if anything more required.... Thank you so much